# Why is my Spring security config throwing 403 on permitAll endpoints also

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to set up a new project using Spring security. The purpose of the projetc is to create few web apis to be used in a react interface. At present, I am using Spring boot 3.2.2 and Spring security 6.2.1

I have most of the things set up. However, for some reasons, the framework always throws 403 on my permitAll() endpoints.

Below is my security chain object:

```
 @Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(httpSecurity);
      return httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/myproject/admin/**") // I have tried removing this condition also
                        .hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public/login") // I have tried without context path also
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/myproject/public/login") // tried with context path also
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) // tried disabling csrf as well
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();

}
```

I have gone through many similar questions and articles and have tried lot of thing including:

1. Using both GET and POST for my login endpoint (Ideally I wanted a POST).
2. Tried disabling csrf
3. Tried putting the endpoint path with and without context path (/api/myproject is my context path)
4. Tried specifying HTTP POST verb as shown above
5. Also tried the above config with everything removed and just 1 rule for login route

None of these have worked for me so far. However If a permitAll everything like:

```
return httpSecurity
            .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
```

then it works for me and makes all the endpoints public including the login endpoint.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong for whitelisting only the login endpoint as public. Can some one please help.

Edit: Adding the controller code below:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/public")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> generateUserToken(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        log.info("generateUserToken Started");
        String token = loginService.login(loginRequest.getEmailId(), loginRequest.getPwd());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new LoginResponse(token));
    }

}
```

The postman cUrl for the API call is:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/api/myproject/public/login' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=9E2DD3E4A04619324786B0F595BD96FD' \
--data-raw '{
    "emailId": "dkjkaj@gmail.com",
    "pwd": "jhdsjhdj"
}'
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the Controller and also the API call itself.

Comment: @Slevin added the details that you asked.

Comment: According to your controller the login endpoint is `http://localhost:8080/public/login` - there is no *api* nor *myproject* somewhere to find in the route. Thus, the endpoint you call is not provided by your application (given that you haven't prefixed your RestController endpoints with a dedicated prefix).

Comment: @Slevin /api/myproject is the context path of my spring boot application and it is defined in the application.properties

Answer (score 0):

Your cURL command is a GET not a POST. You must provide the verb with `-X POST`

In postman you put a body but didn't set POST in the drop down of the verbs. Yes it is weird when you put a body it does not automatically switch.

Comment: sorry abt the curl in the post. However, I am trying with a POST verb only and it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possibilities I can think of.

1. There is a problem with authenticationProvider() added.
2. This point may be obvious but as `/public/login` is `POST` endpoint, from the browser, it will give you 403 as browser attempts for `GET`.
3. You should add the `/error` URL to permitAll permission because any page you try to access that requires authentication redirects to the login page through the `/error` redirection.
   `.requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()`

Full configuration after adding the above permissions

```
return httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/myproject/admin/**")
                        .hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/error")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/myproject/public/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .build();
```